# Copy a variable in shell script (Linux)

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal

How can I copy a variable to another variable in a shell script?

Assuming the user has passed in `$1`, how can its value be copied to another variable?

I assume it would look something like this...

```
cp $1 $2

echo "Copied value: $2"
```

Comment: why `cp`? what's wrong with `x="$1"` then echo "copied value:$x"

Comment: He has a Barbeque, but He wants his chicken roasted only with a Rocket Propeller!

Comment: +1 for most excellent use of `cp` this year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `cp` is used to `copy files and directories`. To define variables, you just have to use the following syntax:

```
v=$1
```

#### Example

```
$ cat a
echo "var v=$v"
v=$1
echo "var v=$v"
$ ./a 23         <---- we execute the script
var v=           <---- the value is not set
var v=23         <---- the value is already set
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `cp` is for copying files and directories only (as the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cp) states)

Secondly, it is not possible to assign to an argument variable ($0..$1..$n). They are meant to be read only.

You can do this instead:

```
input2=$1
```

It will copy the value of `$1` to a new variable called `$input2`

Answer (score 0):

```
val=$1  
echo "Copied Value : $val"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `cp` which is for copying files.

Just use

```
v=$1
```

and echo it:

```
echo "Copied Variable: $v"
```

Comment: why repeating things that had been said before?

Answer (score 0):

i've found  set --  to be a very useful command to set the positional parameters.  e.g. in the example you gave, and well answered:

```
cp file1 file2
```

copies "file1" to "file2".   frequently when i work with a few files, I'll  do this instead:

```
set -- file1 file2
cp $1 $2
```

and if you want to reverse the names in the variables:

```
set -- $2 $1        # puts the current "$2" value in "$1", and vice versa, then
cp $1 $2            # copies what was   file2   contents back to file1.
```

this without using any "named" variables, which you've already seen.  my more common use is like:

```
set -- ${1%.txt}    # strips a ".txt" suffix 
set -- $1 $1.out $1.err   # sets 2nd to <whatever>.out and 3rd to <whatever>.err, so
cmd $1.txt > $2 2>$3      # puts stdout in  ...out  and stderr in ...err
```

v